# How to Use Element ID to getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a script that will `findElementById` across multiple frames and will highlight/change the text color. The script works so that when you `mouseover` each word of "The quick brown fox," the word under your pointer will be red and highlighted in yellow. The same word in frame2 will be red/highlighted as well. Note that the element ids are identical to the class name(s).

```
<html><head><title>Test</title>
  <script>
    function hey(id)
      {document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
      document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.color = "red";
      window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";} 
    function bye(id)
      {document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
      document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
      window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
      window.parent.frames["frame2"].document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="w1" class="w1 w4" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">The</a> 
  <a id="w2" class="w2" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">quick</a>
  <a id="w3" class="w3" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">brown</a> 
  <a id="w4" class="w1 w4" onmouseover="hey(this.id)" onmouseout="bye(this.id)">fox</a>
</body></html>
```

Now I want to edit this script so that it takes the id and finds elements by class. For example, when you `mouseover` "fox" the id="w4". I want to find "w4" in the link's class so that both "The" and "fox" will be red/highlighted whenever either is moused over. I can't figure out how to use `getElementsByClassName` using values from the id. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just pass the class name as argument: `getElementsByClassName(id)`. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName. Btw, you can directly pass the element to the event handler instead of searching for it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `getElementsByClassName` returns an array you have to loop over it. try the below code.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(id);

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` does _not_ return an array, it returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList).

Comment: Oh, I typed "i>elements" rather than "i<elements". My bad. Now it's working.

Comment: @jcoat Actually it was my bad, first time I had a typo, it was ">" and then I have updated the code.